# IntelliJ - use imported modules as dependencies like maven projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt

I've been asking myself this question for a couple of years but never really found the solution.

I used to work with eclipse (on maven java projects). I could import a project -let's call it 'proj-A'- and if one of proj-A's dependencies was found in the workspace with the same exact version, eclipse would use that project's source instead of the jar from the repository. This way I could edit a library and see the changes in the project that used it right away.

For example, in Eclipse, if proj-A depended on dep-B-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT, I could import proj-A and dep-B in the same workspace, and if dep-B version was 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT I could see the live changes in dep-B sources from proj-A classes.

I'm now working in scala in IntelliJ. I don't seem to be able to do that. what's the best workflow if you want to avoid publishing the library and then reloading the whole project that uses it along with all its dependencies every time?

If I import proj-A as sbt project I can find dep-B snapshot jar in the libraries (loaded from some repo, be it local or remote), and I can't see the code changes to the dep-B module imported in the same intellij project (i.e. the equivalent of eclispe workspace).

If I manually remove the dep-B jar and add the dep-B module as a dependency for proj-A I'm forced to do it everytime I reimport proj-A for some reason.

I'm not sure there's a way of doing this as straightforward as the eclipse way (automatic), but maybe you know something I don't ...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work out of box for dependencies, which are imported to the project as modules, no additional settings needed. At least for Java.

Just do not run a Maven goal, that would use dependencies from the repository.

Comment: and that just works for the maven plugin, not sbt, right?

Comment: I have never tried SBT, I merely described how Maven works in IntelliJ compared to your experience in Eclipse. If it does not work for you than you should report a bug.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess what I'm looking for is missing in the sbt plugin then

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti did you manage to add the second project as a dependency in intelij + sbt?

Comment: @Meo A bit late to the party, but I'd appreciate some clarification - I have a project that is run locally using the tomcat7:run maven goal. Does this mean I can't use local dependency resolution for this project?

Comment: @Hikaru755 If you mean, that tomcat7:run will use all dependencies only from your local/remote maven repository, then yes. I start my Tomcat/Jetty programmatically because of that - that way I have to 'mvn install' only maven modules from other IntelliJ projects.

Comment: @Meo could you elaborate on how to do that programmatically? I'm currently running a maven install of the dependency project in the before-launch of the build configuration for the project I'm starting to work around this, but that takes quite some time.

Comment: @Hikaru755 like this: http://pastebin.com/dYFVSFNC  - you could probably find a better implementation of this.